# JAVA-SQL- Data Migration - ResultSets comparing Failing JUnit test

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, data-migration

I CANNOT get this JUnit Test to pass for the life of me.  Can somebody point out where this has gone wrong.  I am doing a data migration(MSSQL SERVER 2005), but I have the sourceDBUrl and the targetDCUrl the same URL so to narrow it down to syntax errors.  So that is what I have, a syntax error.  I am comparing the results of a table for the query

```
SELECT programmeapproval, resourceapproval FROM tr_timesheet WHERE timesheetid = ?
```

and the test always fails, but passes for other junit tests I have developed.  I created 3 diffemt resultSetsEqual methods and none work.  Yet, some other JUnit tests I have developed have PASSED.  THE QUERY:

**SELECT timesheetid, programmeapproval, resourceapproval FROM tr_timesheet**

**Returns three columns**

- **timesheetid**    (PK,int, not null)        (populated with a range of
  numbers 2240 - 2282)
- **programmeapproval** (smallint,not null)         (populated with the
  number 1 in every field)
- **resourceapproval**    (smallint, not null)    (populated with a number
  1 in every field)

When I run the query that is embedded in the code  it only returns one row with the programmeapproval and resourceapproval columns and both field populated with the number 1.

I have all jdbc drivers correctly installed and tested for connectivity.  The JUnit Test is failing at this point according to the IDE.

```
assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual2(sourceVal,targetVal));
```

**This is the code:**

/****THIS IS A JUNIT CLASS*******?

```
package a7.unittests.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Types;
import org.junit.Test;
import artemispm.tritonalerts.TimesheetAlert;


public class UnitTestTimesheetAlert {

@Test
public void testQUERY_CHECKALERT() throws Exception{


UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select programmeapproval, resourceapproval from tr_timesheet where timesheetid = ?");
stmt.setInt(1, 2240);
ResultSet sourceVal = stmt.executeQuery();

stmt = conTarget.prepareStatement("select programmeapproval, resourceapproval from tr_timesheet where timesheetid = ?");
stmt.setInt(1,2240);
ResultSet targetVal = stmt.executeQuery();
assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual2(sourceVal,targetVal));
}}
```

/********END*********/

/****THIS IS A REGULAR CLASS*****/

```
package a7.unittests.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class UnitTestHelper {





static String sourceDBUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=a7itm;user=a7user;password=a7user";
static String targetDBUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=a7itm;user=a7user;password=a7user";




public Connection getConnection(String url)throws Exception{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
}
public boolean resultSetsEqual3 (ResultSet rs1, ResultSet rs2) throws SQLException {
    int col = 1;
    //ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs1.getMetaData();
    //int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
    while (rs1.next() && rs2.next()) {
        final Object res1 = rs1.getObject(col);
        final Object res2 = rs2.getObject(col);
        // Check values
        if (!res1.equals(res2)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s and %s aren't equal at common position %d",
                res1, res2, col));
        }

        // rs1 and rs2 must reach last row in the same iteration
        if ((rs1.isLast() != rs2.isLast())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The two ResultSets contains different number of columns!");
        }


    }
    return true;
}
public boolean resultSetsEqual (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{
    while(source.next())
    {
        target.next();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
        int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
        for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
        {
            if(source.getObject(i) != target.getObject(i))
            {

                return false;

            }

        }

    }

    return true;
}

public boolean resultSetsEqual2 (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{
    while(source.next())
    {
        target.next();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
        int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
        for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
        {
            if(source.getObject(i).equals(target.getObject(i)))
            {

                return false;

            }

        }

    }

    return true;
}
}
```

/***END********/

/****PASTED NEW CLASS - THIS IS A JUNIT TEST CLASS****/

```
package a7.unittests.dao;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestDatabaseConnection {

@Test

public void testConnection() throws Exception{

    UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
    Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
    Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);
    assertTrue(con != null && conTarget != null);

}
```

}

/*****END******/

Comment: failed with assertion error?

Comment: In the future, please only include code which is _actually_ relevant to the question at hand - you've pasted far too much.  Other notes:  In Java, the only thing you can compare with `==` or `!=` are integral types (including char), booleans, and references.  As of JUnit 4.0 (which you appear to be using), there is no difference between test classes and 'regular' classes; thus, there's no need to throw exceptions in test/validation code (which would be misleading, anyways).  Always attempt to use the most appropriate `assert*`, based on what you're actually verifying (`assertNotNull()`, say).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You returned `false` when objects were `equal` to each other. In this method I changed condition to `not equals`.

```
public boolean resultSetsEqual2 (ResultSet source, ResultSet target) throws SQLException{
    while(source.next())
    {
        target.next();
        ResultSetMetaData metadata = source.getMetaData();
        int count = metadata.getColumnCount();
        for (int i =1; i<=count; i++)
        {
             if(!source.getObject(i).equals(target.getObject(i))) //added !
             {
                  return false;
             }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the source of his problem.  Could you also offer some other recommendations about the state of the _rest_ of his code (even if only in this method)?  Don't just seek to answer the question at hand, also seek to enlighten your fellow developers.  (Good spot, by the way, +1).

Comment: That is nuts such a little error and so much time, thanks alot.  I just needed a little peer review.

Comment: @user1865053 No problem. Other code is not bad. But don't use `!=` operator for object comparison in `resultSetsEqual`. Good luck.